# Как настроить openssl php 5.5 на windows?

Tags: php, openssl

Не получается использовать openssl.
Настроил вроде все как полагается. Установил dll.
Закинул файлы libeay32.dll и ssleay32.dll в папку System32

И пытаюсь протестировать

```
$config = [
    'private_key_bits' => 512,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
];

// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
var_dump($res);
```

получаю false

Comment: Предоставьте файл openssl.cnf. И после не большого знакомства с документацией надо было его запихивать в папку с php а в переменной PATH прописать путь к php!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ARACOOOL/e9b5b6dfd584b83b0ae1
файл openssl.cnf

Я добавил его в корень php. Путь к php прописан в PATH. Но все равно не работает